# Multiline JAVA_OPTS in setenv.sh

Tags: java, tomcat7

I'm trying to setup my `setenv.sh` on Ubuntu 12/Tomcat 7.
Tomcat has been installed with apt-get
I've tried to create a multiline `JAVA_OPTS` variable but keep running into error messages.

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server \
-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

: not foundtomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 4: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m"

: not foundtomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 3: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've updated it to this, but at the echo location only the last line is displayed.

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms704m -Xmx704m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/share/scripts/on_server_crash.sh"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat7"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:NewSize=256m"
echo $JAVA_OPTS
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=12 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseTLAB"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$NR_JAR -Dnewrelic.environment=production"
echo $JAVA_OPTS
export JAVA_OPTS
```

When I try "each command on its own line" without the export option, I get "unrecognized option -server

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms704m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx704m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/share/scripts/on_server_crash.sh"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat7"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxNewSize=256m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:NewSize=256m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:SurvivorRatio=12"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseTLAB"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$NR_JAR"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dnewrelic.environment=production"
echo JAVA_OPTS
```

Comment: Please you the {} button for code - this will format it for you.

Comment: Could you please show the whole line you are trying to execute on the shell, i.e. `java $JAVA_OPTS ....`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version based on bmargulies's suggestion. However, it seems to only set the last invocation to JAVA_OPTS and not include the previous statements.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/72476/clean-way-to-write-complex-multi-line-string-to-a-variable may be your answer

Comment: found that and tried that. to no avail. There's something weird going on. I tried various of the things above on an older server with tomcat6/jdk6 etc and it works fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Hmm, deleted the whole file and recreated it, and now it works.....
Now using this style

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS\
 -server\
 -Xms704m\
 -Xmx704m\
 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/share/scripts/on_server_crash.sh\
 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError\
 -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat7\
 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m\
 -XX:MaxNewSize=256m\
 -XX:NewSize=256m\
 -XX:SurvivorRatio=12\
 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0\
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC\
 -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode\
 -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing\
 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled\
 -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled\
 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC\
 -XX:+UseParNewGC\
 -XX:+UseTLAB\
 -Djava.awt.headless=true\
 -javaagent:$NR_JAR\
 -Dnewrelic. environment=production"
```

Comment: It's extremely sensitive to the location of the ".
If tomcat 7 doesn't start correctly anymore. it's prob something to do w that

Answer (score 12):

You'd be better off with:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server "
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx512m"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

Comment: I tried that but if I echo JAVA_OPTS at the end, I just see -Mms512m -Xmx512m (in stead of -server - XMs512m -Mmx512m)

Comment: How can this work? assign twice and expect to get concatenation?

Comment: This is the standard way for many properties to be set - you'll often see it in app servers and so on (tomcat, glassfish etc). This would have been my suggested answer too

Comment: @DariuszWawer Note that the original question's version also worked this way. The shell is defined to expand the RHS before assigning to the LHS.

Answer (score 4):

Wound up using something similar to Marc, but with escapes for spaces in property definitions

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS \
-DFOO=\"bar bar\" \
-DBAZ=\"bar2 bar2\" "
```