# Grails 3 war always in dev environment on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, jenkins

I am using Grails 3.0.1 and have the standard environments defined. 
When I deploy my app on my Tomcat 7 via Jenkins, It always deploys in development mode and never in production since I use Grails 3.

The only thing I have changed in my build.gradle is the following line:

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

This is my build config in Jenkins.

[image: My Jenkins Build Config]

Building and deployment works well but environment. 
I know this because it does not touches mysql at all and I have this in my index.gsp which shows me the

```
    ${grails.util.Environment.current.name}
```

Do you have any advice for me?

Edit:
What I've tried until now:

- Using "prod war" instead of "war" only as target

Comment: Have you tried changing your `Targets` setting in Jenkins to `prod war` instead of just `war`?

Comment: Yes, sadly I did and it changed nothing.

Comment: have you tried adding environment config settings to your tomcat setenv.sh/bat ? -Dgrails.env=prod  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926260/multiline-java-opts-in-setenv-sh