# setting option for JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, server, setenv

I'm kinda lost in the java-options world

I've got a server and I'm doing some research for tuning issue

I found some options that I want to set for my jvm used by Tomcat
(ie Xmx, Xms)

where have I got to put thoswe settings? in setenv?

I tryed:

```
Export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xmx512m -Xms512m"
```

then restart Tomcat and

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize'
```

gave me (like before)

> uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1035993088

I think I missed something

Plus I've got 64bit system and 8GB RAM, accrding to my research I found that I can set Xmx to 6GB, but none information about Xms. Any advice? thank you all

Comment: Their are two optiona to do it. One create a seperate file setenv.sh or edit catalina.sh. Go to line no 54 in calatina.sh. Probably help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926260/multiline-java-opts-in-setenv-sh

Comment: Followed the suggested actions but in every case `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize'` return `uintx MaxHeapSize := 1035993088`

Comment: `setenv.sh` is the right place, but you can also set the variable in the shell and export it. Will be picked up as long as there is no assignment in setenv.sh of it, which would override it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "java" command has nothing to do with your running Tomcat! This starts just a second JVM.

If you want to see the arguments with which your Tomcat JVM was actually started, then on Linux use `ps eww -p <pid>`  or `pargs <pid>`  on Solaris.

Btw, CATALINA_OPTS is prefered over JAVA_OPTS, the latter one is used for all Java processes started by the tomcat Installation, and CATALINA_OPTS only for the main server process.

Comment: thanks, with ps eww -p <pid> I can see the changes. Can you help me with the second part of the question:  I've got 64bit system and 8GB RAM, according to my research I found that I can set Xmx to 6GB, what value can be used for Xms?

Comment: Xms is not so important. It defined the inital size of the heap, the amount that is allocated right at the start of the JVM. You may set it to 1G or so. You can also set it to the same value as Xmx, then the whole will be allocated at the beginning.